# A general object sort method for python

Tags: python, hash

I want to generate something like hash for almost every object. It is currently implemented as:

```
hashlib.sha256(pickle.dumps(something))
```

.

However, it generates different hash for `something = {"a": 1, "b": 2}` and `something={"b":2, "a":1}`. I really want the generated hash to be identical for them. Thus I want a function that sorts a *general* object (maybe something contains a dictionary as an attribute) and make sure `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` and `something={"b":2, "a":1}` pickle to the same bytes.

Is this possible?

Or is there a better way to generate such hash?

Edit:
I don't care if data types are altered. For example, `sorted(something.items())` can do the job for a dictionary. But I want a more general method.

Comment: Dictionary can't be sorted anyway, as it has no order. Unless you convert it to a different data structure like list of tuple or OrderedDict , you can't sort it.

Answer (score -1):

Look at OrderedDict object in collections https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: No. The input object is not in my control and may be an ordinary dictionary.

Comment: So ?
You can cast it into OrderedDict.
Implicitly, {"a": 1, "b": 2} and {"b": 2, "a": 1} will be transform into the same OrderedDict